# Setting system time in embedded Linux with GPS PPS on GPIO

Tags: c, linux, gps, embedded-linux, gpio

I've got a GPS with the PPS coming in on a GPIO on my non-networked embedded Linux board running 2.6.37.

I'm trying to keep the system clock as accurate as possible (preferably better than 20us accuracy).  I've set the time within a few millis from the serial port GPS and would like to use the the PPS to discipline the clock (is that the correct term?)

I've set up an interrupt that catches the the PPS.

My interrupt handling routine is something like:

```
struct timeval tv;
do_gettimeofday(&tv);
..check that we're really close to a second mark and adjust tv to the nearest second...
do_settimeofday(&tv);
```

Question:

**Do do_gettimeofday/do_settimeofday take significant amounts of time to execute?**

**Is this an acceptable way to approach keeping time?**

I know there's NTP and Linux-PPS, but I don't want the overhead unless there's other subtle considerations to setting system time that I'm not aware of.

Many thanks.

Comment: I have similar need. What was the resolution for this issue ?

Comment: there is also time_pps_kcbind, maybe this adjust the hrtimer to pps ?

Comment: Alas, I did not resolve the issue.  I continue to use the solution proposed in the question, but remain under certain whether this is the best solution.  Can only say that it works well enough the customer is not complaining.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ntpd with PPS if you need accurate and reliable synchronization. ntpd uses tested algorithms written with reliability in mind. The overhead is negligible.